# Rabbitmq .NET Send same message to multiple subscribers in same queue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp

i need to  Send same message to multiple subscribers by one queue. Is there such a possibility ?

I know that i can send one message to subscribers with fanout and couple of queues using exchange, but i don't need that.

Any advises ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. With rabbit, a message in a queue is consumed at most once time.

You could let each of the subscriber create its own queue at runtime however, which you plug on an exchange, and tag this queue autodelete. The exchange (if topic or fanout) will correctly duplicate messages.